# Как пребразовать IntStream в for. Как применяется IntUnaryOperator

Tags: java, java-stream

Код из codesignal.com Помогите разобраться, как он работает. В частности, можно ли `IntStream` переделать как for для понимания.

`IntUnaryOperator` - почему выбран и что он делает. Представление о функциональных интерфейсах имею, но на уровне примитивных примеров.

```
boolean solution(char[][] grid) {
    return IntStream.range(0, 9)
        .allMatch(n ->
                  isValid(grid, k -> k, k -> n) &&
                  isValid(grid, k -> n, k -> k) &&
                  isValid(grid, k -> (n / 3) * 3 + k / 3, k -> (n % 3) * 3 + k % 3));
}

boolean isValid(char[][] grid, IntUnaryOperator rowSelector, IntUnaryOperator colSelector) {
    Set<Character> s = new HashSet<>();
    for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        int r = rowSelector.applyAsInt(k);
        int c = colSelector.applyAsInt(k);
        if (grid[r][c] == '.') {
            continue;
        }
        if (s.contains(grid[r][c])) {
            return false;
        }
        s.add(grid[r][c]);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам по себе `IntStream.range(0, 9)` - это примерно как `for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)`.

`allMatch` - это проверка, что все элементы из `stream` соответствуют указанному условию (чтобы `allMatch` вернул true, нужно чтобы для каждого элемента из `stream` предикат вернул `true`). Если переделывать в обычный цикл, то внутри цикла должен быть `if`, который выйдет из цикла, если предикат вернул `false`.

Замена на `for` и `if` будет примерно такая:

```
boolean solution(char[][] grid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        IntPredicate predicate = n ->
                isValid(grid, k -> k, k -> n) &&
                        isValid(grid, k -> n, k -> k) &&
                        isValid(grid, k -> (n / 3) * 3 + k / 3, k -> (n % 3) * 3 + k % 3);

        if (!predicate.test(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

`IntUnaryOperator` - просто функциональный интерфейс, который можно реализовать функцией, принимающей целое число и возвращающим целое число (т.е. операция над целым числом).

Примерно то же самое, что `Function<Integer, Integer>`. В коде метода `isValid` можно заменить `IntUnaryOperator` на `Function<Integer, Integer>` и `applyAsInt` на просто `apply`, и все будет работать как работало.

Answer (score 0):

Заменить `IntStream` на цикл `for` в методе `solution` достаточно просто, но читабельность кода вряд ли улучшится от этого:

```java
boolean solution(char[][] grid) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
        if (!(isValid(grid, k -> k, k -> n) &&
            isValid(grid, k -> n, k -> k) &&
            isValid(grid, k -> (n / 3) * 3 + k / 3, k -> (n % 3) * 3 + k % 3)
        )) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`IntUnaryOperator` в данном случае представляют собой некоторые простые функции для выбора ряда или строки для заданного числа.

1. `isValid(grid, k -> k, k -> n)`
   Здесь `rowSelector` возвращает свой аргумент, а `colSelector` -- константное значение в диапазоне `[0 .. 9)`.
   Таким образом внутри метода `isValid` при подставлении числа `k` в том же диапазоне `[0 .. 9)` будет выполняться итерация *по строкам*: `r ∈ [0..9), c = n` для заданного `n`-го столбца, т.е. выполняется *вертикальная* проверка.
2. `isValid(grid, k -> n, k -> k)`
   Аналогично, `rowSelector` возвращает константное значение в диапазоне `[0 .. 9)`, а `colSelector` -- свой аргумент, то есть внутри метода `isValid` будет выполняться итерация по *столбцам* для заданной `n`-ой строки: `r = n, с ∈ [0..9)` -- выполняется *горизонтальная* проверка
3. `isValid(grid, k -> (n / 3) * 3 + k / 3, k -> (n % 3) * 3 + k % 3)` - для проверки квадратов 3х3 внутри входного массива символов 9х9.

То есть, изменяя вычисление индексов, достаточно использовать одну и ту же функцию для проверки строки / столбца / квадрата.

---

Решение в старом "нефункциональном" стиле могло бы выглядеть так (с использованием вложенного цикла):

```java
static boolean solution(char[][] grid) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
        Set<Character> row = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Character> col = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Character> sqr = new HashSet<>();
        for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
            // рассматриваем строку
            char r = grid[n][k];
            if (r != '.' && !row.add(r)) return false;
            
            // рассматриваем столбец
            char c = grid[k][n];
            if (c != '.' && !col.add(c)) return false;
            
            // рассматриваем квадрат 3х3
            char s = grid[(n / 3) * 3 + k / 3][ (n % 3) * 3 + k % 3];
            if (s != '.' && !sqr.add(s)) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Очевидно, здесь часть кода дублируется, отличаясь только способом вычисления индексов и добавлением элементов в соответствующий сет для проверки уникальности.